# Reading multiple excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[Sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Vwn.png)I'm new to python. Trying to read multiple excel files in folder and make it separate DataFrames.

Is the below code correct?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
os.chdir(r'/Users/try/Documents/data')

df = ([])
def readdataframe(the_list):
    for element in the_list:
        print(element)
        df[element] = pd.read_excel(element, 'shee1')

readdataframe(["24032020_D_KWH.xlsx","25032020_D_KWH.xlsx","26032020_D_KWH.xlsx","27032020_D_KWH.xlsx"])
```

I get below error when I execute

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is: you are using a string as list index but this should be an int. Can you post the whole output of your program? `element` is probably a string and that is giving you the error. Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks! It got solved with below answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing df = ([]) with df=pd.DataFrame() should do the trick. You didn't define your df as a pandas dataframe.

After a test this is what I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r"path to your excel files")

the_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"path to your excel files"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            the_list.append(file)

def readdataframe(the_list):
    df = pd.DataFrame() #define df as an empty pandas DataFrame
    for element in the_list:
        #print(element)
        df[element] = pd.read_excel(element, squeeze=True)
    return df

print(readdataframe(the_list))
```

Output:

```
   file1.xlsx  file2.xlsx  file3.xlsx
0           1           6          11
1           2           7          12
2           3           8          13
3           4           9          14
4           5          10          15
```

I'm sorry but it is considered a bad practice to upload your files, and I'm not going to download it. Nothing personal, just basic digital hygiene.

Now onto the explanation.
As you may have noticed in this line

```
df[element] = pd.read_excel(element, squeeze=True)
```

I"ve added

> squeeze=True

What this parameter does is convert the dataframe that was returned into a pandas Series (one-dimensional array, think of it as your general python list), because I had only 1 column in each of my files and

> df[element] =

syntax sets "element" as a column name in your dataframe where you save your data. So, this way will only work if data in your file is one-dimensional (only 1 column) If not, you should probably look into [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) or [pandas DataFrame join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) depending on the uniformity of the data shape in the files and your needs.

if you are willing to get multiple dataframes instead this is what I'm suggesting.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r"path to your excel files")

the_list = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"path to your excel files"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            the_list.append(file)

def readdataframe(the_list):
    df_dict = {}
    for element in the_list:
        df_dict[element] = pd.read_excel(element)
    return df_dict

print(readdataframe(the_list))
```

This way you are getting a python dictionary(hashtable) that contains your dataframe objects as a value and filename as a key.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with above, I got 'ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series'

Comment: Can a data frame start with number? if so should can I add a character say ' D' before number

Comment: @user13153021 Please let me get to my PC and try running your code. While I'm getting there could you post some sample data from a couple of your Excel files?

Comment: @user13153021 I've updated my answer, please, take a look

Comment: where can I add the sheet name. in my code I given sheet name. pl check

Comment: just use pd.read_excel(element, sheet_name="your sheet name")

Comment: added sample data as image . updated. Thanks . I still get the error. ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Comment: In your case, you should probably skip the first 4 rows, since the actual data starts at 5th row. 
pd.read_excel() supports many different parameters, including skiprows, so it would be pd.read_excel(element, sheet_name="your sheet name", skiprows = [0,1,2,3])
I highly suggest you to read about pd.read_excel() functionality in the pandas documentation.

Comment: Super. Thanks! the code worked fine and printed all DataFrame. What is the name of DataFrame if I had to call individually.

Comment: You would call it as df_dict[element], where element is the name of your file.
If I was of any help, please consider accepting my answer and upvoting.

Comment: I tried df_dict[20032020_D_KWH.xlsx].head(), df_dict[20032020_D_KWH].head(), df_dict 20032020_D_KWH.xlsx.head() & df_dict 20032020_D_KWH.head() . It says            
    df_dict[20032020_D_KWH.xlsx].head(5)
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: I think because he file name starts with numeric?

Comment: Your file name should be a string, so this is what your call should be:
df_dict["20032020_D_KWH.xlsx"].head()

Comment: I tried df_dict["20032020_D_KWH.xlsx"].head(). it says - ----> 1 df_dict["20032020_D_KWH.xlsx"].head()

NameError: name 'df_dict' is not defined